# How to get Product Information of an Account?

Tags: community, query, php

In an account view there is information related to account. I need to get name, phone number, billing address of the account.
My query for getting name, phone number and billing address is `"SELECT Name, Phone, BillingStreet, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry, BillingCity FROM Account;"`

Is there any way I can get Product Information (shown in attachment)? I have tried `"SELECT Name, Phone, BillingStreet, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry, BillingCity, ProductInformation FROM Account;"` However this is does not work, any thoughts?

Thanks!

[image: Product Information]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product Information is just the name of the section on the page layout which relates to the user interface and is not reflected in the database. The fields in your screenshot are not standard account fields that come with vanilla Salesforce, which means they were custom fields created by an administrator. In order to query them, you will need to know their field API names, which will end with `__c`. For example, Current Vapor might be called `Current_Vapor__c`.

---

If you are using Salesforce Classic, you can view the account fields this way:

> From Setup, enter Account in the Quick Find box, then select Fields under Accounts.

Field Label is what you see on the Account page when looking at a record, but API name is what you will use to query that field.

---

If you are using Lightning, you can view the Account object and its fields by following these instructions:

> From Setup, at the top of the page, select Object Manager. Next, select Account, and then Fields & Relationships.

There you will see all the fields on the Account with their label and API name (listed as "Field Name"). The Field Label is what you see on the record page, but the Field Name is what you will use to query.